# PHP 5.4 + Oracle 11.2g : return collection in a cursor

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

Assume, in Oracle 11.2g

the following type:

```
create type a_type is table of varchar2(30);
```

the following record type:

```
type a_record is record(id              number(18)
                       ,a_collection    a_type
                       );
```

the following cursor type:

```
type a_cursor is ref cursor return a_record;
```

the following stored proc definition

```
function a_function return a_cursor;
```

When executing the function from PHP 5.4 to retrieve the cursor, I get:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT
```

While I know that collections can be returned individually using:

```
oci_new_collection
oci_bind_by_name
```

...it appears that the problem is caused by the inclusion of a_collection in the cursor.

My question is: Does anyone know whether a way exists to return a_collection in a PHP 5.4 cursor from Oracle 11.2g?

Comment: A note that to work around the problem ...in a very ugly way, I now convert a_collection to a | delimited varchar2 which I am then able to return as part of the cursor as it is a simple type. I'm not happy at all with the approach but I have no idea what else to do at this point. Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just a quick update for anyone interested ...given that I have never found a cursor capable solution, my approach these days is to use XML to return complex objects. It is a bit bloated and overhead intensive I feel for returning multiple rows, but it works. JSON is also presumably a "lighter" possibility but I haven't got round to investigating Oracle's JSON support as yet unfortunately